# Disguising attacks through well known bugs

Tags: attacks

In the movie "Minority Report", the Precogs can foresee murders and store in video log files that can be inspected in the future. There was a known "won't fix" bug where these visions would "echo" and therefore were discarded by operators, but still recorded.

[spoiler] One of the main plots is an unsolved murder, which, in the end, is revealed that a "bad guy" who was aware of this bug hires an assassin to kill somebody using a specific method knowing the precogs would foresee it and send the police after this first assassin, only to actually kill the person using the exact same method. The operators would see it and discard it as "echo", allowing him to go unpunished.  Fortunately, since there were video logs, that allowed the "good guy" to compare both cases and catch him. [/spoiler]

Is there any similar attack in real life where a bad actor uses a well-known bug to disguise his attack and get unnoticed?

Comment: Uh, sure? Rewriting timestamps or changing the computer time then changing it back again? Or timing an attack for Friday at 7pm, knowing that the SOC might not get notified until Monday morning?

Comment: Or a distraction? Where you launch a DDoS to hide a brute force on an adjacent system?

Comment: What you are actually describing is a simple ***process vulnerability***. You exploit the weakness in the defender's *process* to carry out your attack.

Comment: Note that in the film, the "echo" visions are usually not even recorded - the echos are force-ignored.  The plot-specific echo is only recorded (and incompletely, at that) because the usual technician isn't there to make it be ignored while attempting to record a different vision altogether.

Comment: @schroeder - Rewriting timestamps are different, since the attacker is not exploiting a bug to cover his tracks. A distraction looks more like it.

Comment: Being able to rewrite timestamps is a vulnerability in and of itself...